How to Input Local Images in Autogen with Gemini?
I am trying to use Autogen with Gemini to create a multi-agent framework for one of my projects. However, the project pipeline requires feeding in images stored on my local computer. I know how to input images that are available online, as described in this link. But I am unsure how to feed in images stored locally. Please help me.
